# Syntax error in a simple SQL query

Tags: postgresql, query, syntax

I am using pgAdmin to write a simple SQL INNER JOIN query. However, when I run the code it only will run the first line and give me a syntax error shown below. But, I can select the whole code and it will return the data I am looking for. How can I get this up and running so that I do not have to select the code I am trying to run every time?

CODE:

```
SELECT * FROM payment
INNER JOIN customer
ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id;
```

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 665: SELECT * FROM payment

SQL state: 42601
Character: 18909
```

Comment: There's no `;` on the previous statement.

Comment: Or, there could be a syntax error in one of the 664 preceding lines.

Comment: So, that is just the thing if I just hit run this code it will jump back to this saying there is a syntax error when in fact I have spelled everything correctly.

Comment: Also, there doesn't need to be a ';' at the end of the statement in pgAdmin to end a query.

Comment: What happens if that is the **only** query in your editor? What happens if you do properly end the previous (or actually _all_) statements with `;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though pqAdmin might not require `;` at the end of a query, if you have multiple queries in the same script, `;` might be required to separate the queries. This happens in MySQL and phpMyAdmin.

So, please add `;` just before `SELECT`, and see if that works.

Comment: Postgres most certainly requires a `;` to terminate a statement.

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed the issue. I normally put a ; at the end of a statement but had forgotten one. This makes life so much easier now.

Comment: This is why some SQL Server uses add a semicolon _before_ each statement -- this ensures that the previous one is terminated without having to scan 600+ lines of code.